# How do I encrypt a new user's password using the useradd command?

Tags: command-line, encryption, passwd, useradd

I would like to create an encrypted login password for a new user while using the `useradd` command in the CLI. I know that using option `-p` will allow me to create a password, but using this option does not encrypt the password. I also know that I can create an encrypted password using the `passwd [username]` command separately after the new user has been created through `useradd`, but like I said, I would like to know how to create an encrypted password through the `useradd` command.

Comment: Aren't all passwords encrypted in `/etc/shadow`?

Answer (score 2):

You could use Perl:

```bsh
perl -e "print crypt(\"foo\", \"\$6\$$(</dev/urandom tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | head -c 32)\$\")"
```

Or Python with the `crypt` module:

```bsh
python -c "import crypt; print crypt.crypt(\"foo\", \"\$6\$$(</dev/urandom tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | head -c 32)\$\")"
```

- `foo`: the password to encrypt
- `$6`: the encryption type, in this case SHA-512
- `$(</dev/urandom tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | head -c 32)`: the encryption salt, in this case a random 32 character string.

In conjunction with `useradd`:

```bsh
useradd [...] -p"$(perl -e "print crypt(\"foo\", \"\$6\$$(</dev/urandom tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | head -c 32)\$\")")" [...]
```

Or:

```bsh
useradd [...] -p"$(python -c "import crypt; print crypt.crypt(\"foo\", \"\$6\$$(</dev/urandom tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | head -c 32)\$\")")" [...]
```

Comment: perl command is giving an error: `Final $ should be \$ or $name at -e line 1, within string`

Comment: +1 for the two random salt characters

Comment: The `crypt` module is deprecated in Python since version 3.11 and will be removed in version 3.13.

Answer (score 1):

You could skip the whole administrator-created-password user administration hassle by creating the userid, then using `passwd --expire` on it. From `man passwd`:

```
   -e, --expire
       Immediately expire an account's password. This in effect can force
       a user to change his/her password at the user's next login.
```

Answer (score 1):

Since passwd does not support --stdin in Ubuntu you could try this:

```
perl -e "print crypt('password','sa');"
```

see https://administratosphere.wordpress.com/2011/06/16/generating-passwords-using-crypt3/

Comment: `passwd` on Ubuntu doesn't support the `--stdin` flag

Answer (score 1):

You can use "useradd -p ENCRYPTED-passwd", you need the whole password, including the definition of encryption type, and you need to escape any and all $'s, other than that it seems to works fine.

Simply create a random, disposable user, set their password to what you want to use, then copy their password from the shadow file, copy everything from the first to the second ":" in the shadow file, and use that after the -p.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me w/Ubuntu 18.04 LTS:

```
echo 'your_password' > /tmp/pw.txt
pw="$(makepasswd --crypt-md5 --clearfrom=/tmp/pw.txt)"
sudo useradd -p "${pw}" your_username
rm -f /tmp/pw.txt
```

This may first require installing `makepasswd` using *(on Ubuntu or Debian; google for other distros):*

```
sudo apt install makepasswd
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use openssl like so:

```
encrypted=`echo $password | openssl passwd -6 -stdin`
```

For security reasons, you may also want to clear the variable's value asap:

```
password=
```

Although I don't think that changes much of anything.

Finally use the `encrypted` variable on the `useradd` command line:

```
... --password "$encrypted" ...
```